# Store Arabic character in Netezza N3001

Tags: character-encoding, arabic, netezza, datastage

I have Arabic data in my source DB2 database. I am using DataStage as ETL tool and my target is Netezza. On loading the data I am seeing '???' in Datastage and in Netezza as well.

Please guide me on how to read the data in Netezza and in Datastage and what all encoding to use .

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gnanesh

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just using `varchar` columns instead of `nvarchar` columns. After putting some Arabic characters in a file,

```
create table so as select * from external '/home/nz/test.dat' (arabic nvarchar(100));
```

Selecting from this new table returns the characters.

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped! If this was indeed the answer, it would be great if you [accepted it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).